# How to call a subdirectory of the current working directory correctly with glob

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to search all files in a subdirectory of my current working directory, this is part of a bigger code where I choose different subfolders and make some manupulations of files in them. But I don't want to call the whole file path each time.:

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir("C:/Users/John")
for i in glob.glob("/subfolder/**"):
   print(i)
```

So if there is something in subfolder this code should print it. But somehow glob.glob can't finde the folder

Comment: `glob.glob("subfolder/**"):`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added / in front of subfolder which is not directly accessible. Try removing it. This code works for me.

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir("C:/Users/John")
for i in glob.glob("subfolder/**"):
   print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand...

You want display the files of your subfolder ?

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir("C:/Users/John")
for e in glob.glob("./your_subfolder_name/*"):
   print(e)
```

This display all the files in the folder :

```
C:/Users/John/your_subfolder_name
```

Comment: Yeah this is part of a bigger code where I choose different subfolders and make some manupulation of files in them. But I don't want to call the whole filepath each time.